# How I can detect swipe on Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityscript

[Look image for understend what I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2NlpI.png)

I found how to determine the touch on the top or bottom but I need more detail
I showed in the picture what I need.

Give a hint please